# How to use git on an adapted file?

Tags: git

I'd like to take code from another project and adapt it for use in my program.
I only need a couple of files from the project and **don't want to make a fork of the whole repo** (the fork wouldn't be functional anyway).
I plan to reformat the code, change the names of some functions, and make some deletions/changes.

I could just copy the necessary files into my source tree and make my modifications, but this would not be future-proof for when the original project changes.
**How should I use git to keep track of changes to the original file and merge them into the modified version that I've incorporated into my project?**

Comment: <pedantry>Fork in this sense is GitHub terminology, and git isnt GitHub. Learning this will help the beginner in git. In git, I would probably call this your clone of the project, with modifications relevant to you. It will be understood as a fork, ofc, but in git documentation forking generally refers to forking a topic branch off of another branch. I mention this only to dispel the myth that GitHub is git. </pedantry>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be better off just copying the files you intend to modify into your project.

Here's why. You [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57547940/26396):

> I only need a couple of files from the project and don't want to make a fork of the whole repo.

Cloning or adding the other project as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) would still get you an entire other repo with all its history. If you only need a couple of files (as in 2–3 files), it's easier to just copy them and move on.

But here's the important part:

> I plan to reformat the code, change the names of some functions, and make some deletions/changes.

Renaming functions and moving code around will make it extremely difficult (not to mention *tedious* and *error-prone*) to merge any changes in the original files.

To give you an example, imagine what would happen if a bug was fixed in a function that you renamed or moved to a different file. You would have to *manually* copy the modified lines from the original file and paste them in their new location. That's assuming those lines are still there and you haven't modified them. On top of that, you would need to do this *every time* the original function changes.

> I could just copy the necessary files into my source tree and make my modifications.

Based on your particular scenario, I'd say that's the [path of least resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_of_least_resistance).

Answer (score 3):

It's still a fork. a small one, if changes are limited to just one file - but a fork. and the most convenient way to keep up to date with the original project's version of the file is merging it. If the project is very active, you may realize that the change can no longer be limited to a single file - single files may get refactored beyond recognition, moved, renamed, or replaced altogether, as a project evolves.